# Relation between a normal subgroup and the center of a Nilpotent group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

$N$ is a proper normal subgroup of group $G$ and $N \cap G'=<e>$ then prove that $N<C(G)$.

If $G$ were abelian and nilpotent then the result would hold trivially.

So, assuming that $G$ is a non-abelian nilpotent group, for any $g\in G$, $n\in N$, $ngn^{-1}g^{-1}\in N$ and $ngn^{-1}g^{-1}\in G'$. This implies that $ngn^{-1}g^{-1}=e$ and therefore, $n\in C(G)$  (since  $ng=gn$ $\forall g \in G)$ and $N\subseteq C(G)$. This implies that $N\leqslant C(G)$. How do we infer that $N < C(G)?$

Can we say that if $N=C(G)$ then since $G'\leqslant C_2(G)$ and $C(G)=C_1(G) \trianglelefteq C_2(G)$ implies that $N \cap G'=G'$ or $N?$

Comment: This is clearly false when $G$ is abelian and $N=G$. Do you want to assume that $G$ is nonabelian?

Comment: @ Derek: If $G$ is abelian and $N \triangleleft G$, then the result holds trivially. So, yes, how do we proceed if $G$ is not abelian?

Comment: If  $G$ is nonabelian, then $G'$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup. In a nilpotent group any nontrivial normal subgroup intersects the centre nontrivially, so $G' \cap C(G) \ne 1$, and hence $C(G)$ is not contained in $N$.

Comment: @Derek: "In a nilpotent group any nontrivial normal subgroup intersects the centre nontrivially...": This exactly is my question. How do we infer this?

Comment: It's a standard property of nilpotent groups. Let $1 \ne N \unlhd G$ with $G$ nilpotent. Then the descending series $N=N_1 >  N_1 >  \cdots > N_{k+1} = 1$ with $N_{i+1} = [G,N_i]$ has length at most the nilpotency class of $G$. The last nontrivial subgroup $N_k$ of the series lies in $N \cap C(G)$.

Comment: @ Derek: "The last nontrivial subgroup $N_k$ of the series lies in $N\cap C(G)$": can you kindly explain this?

Comment: @ Derek: Thanks for the hints, by the way. I will try on my own from here.

Comment: What does $C_2(G)$ stand for? Is $C_1(G) = C(G)$ by definition?